# Script to delete old files(tar) in a directory if the number exceeds 15?

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory

Please anyone can give the solution for this
I'm trying to take gitlab backup to another server, script should delete the old files if the file number in the directory exceeds 15?

Comment: It's relatively easy to count files and delete some if there are more than 15. It's more difficult to determine which are the oldest, you can check the modified timestamp, but if a file has been changed recently it will seem newer than it really is. Is there any timestamp included in the filenames of the tar backups?

Comment: ^ this, or, *after* the files are copied to the directory, are they edited in any way?

Comment: That looks like what logrotate does, or can be configured to do.

Comment: @Arronical well if a file was modified recently it *is* new for most practical purposes. :) But one could store a timestamp in the name anyway.

Comment: Yes, timestamp is included in it and once the backup is converted to tar file will be no modification made on that file, just it will be stored as daily backup.

Comment: @Harsha just curious, but did you try tge answer(s)? Furthermore, what is exactlybthe forjatvforvthe timestamp?

Comment: @JacobVlijm unclear what you are asking. :P

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto whaaat? Did I write that? I must have been using my phone, not checking what it actually spit out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diclaimer:I've tested the following commands with filenames that contain spaces, but not with filenames that contain newlines. I suspect that they will not play nicely with filenames containing the newline character, and would avoid using them if you suspect filenames containing them may be created.

This approach relies on the ctime of the file so if files have any of their attributes changed, they will appear to be newer than their creation time. Only you can decide whether relying on ctime is applicable in your situation. If you'd rather use mtime, change `-printf "%C+ %p\n"` to `-printf "%T+ %p\n"` in the `find` commands.

The following command can be issued inside the directory containing your tar files. This assumes that the filenames are all something like `something.tar`. If the filenames are not of this format, the command will need to be modified, either changing the `-iname '*.tar.'` to `-iname '*.tar.gz*'` if the files are .tar.gz files, or by removing the entire `-iname '*.tar.'` string if you just want to operate on any files in that directory, regardless of filename format.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tar' -printf "%C+ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | head -n -15 | xargs -I{} echo "{}"
```

If this shows you the oldest files, outside of your 15 file limit, then use the following command to delete those files.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tar' -printf "%C+ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | head -n -15 | xargs -I{} rm "{}"
```

By Way of explanation:

- `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tar' -printf "%C+ %p\n"` will list all of the files that end in .tar in `.` (the current directory) without recursing into subdirectories. It then prints the ctime timastamp followed by a space and the file name with a trailing newline character.
- `| sort -n` sorts the output of `find` numerically, so files are listed from oldest to newest (by ctime) .
- `| cut -d ' ' -f 2-` removes the added timestamp that `find` created, but preserves the order of the files listed by `sort`.
- `| head -n -15` trims the bottom 15 items from the output of `cut`.
- `xargs -I{} rm "{}"` runs the `rm` command on each file, ensuring the filename is not split on whitespace.

This can be written as a bash script, with the number of files to retain and the directory on which to operate as variables in the script. It's possible to pass in the directory and file retention count as arguments instead, but I won't cover that here.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_limit=15
dir=/directory/containing/tarfiles

find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tar' -printf "%C+ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | head -n -"$file_limit" | xargs -I{} rm "{}"
```

If you save this script somewhere e.g. `/home/user/trim_old_gits` and ensure that you have given it executable permissions. The script can be run from the command line by entering:

```
/home/user/trim_old_gits
```

Or from within `/home/user`:

```
./trim_old_gits
```

As mentioned in [Jacob](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm)'s marvellous [python answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/886824/320386), using the `cron` utility would be a good way to ensure that this happens on a regular basis, if it's not crucial that the files be deleted immediately, or `inotifywait` if timing is more sensitive.

Comment: Thanks its working. How can I  display the file(s) which has been deleted when I execute this script?

Comment: If you use the `-v` option to the `rm` command each deleted file will be listed.

Comment: I tried it using -v, it is working if I run the script manually. When I use it in cron job to run automatically it is not listing the files?

Comment: If it's run from a cron job, it won't have a terminal to output to. Any output from a cron job will actually be put into an email and will attempt to send it to the email address of the user whose crontab you've used. To send the output to a file add `> /path/to/a/file` to the very end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that both `ctime` and `mtime` are no guarantee that you actually delete the ***oldest*** files, depending on what happened to the files in between, the script below deletes the files, exceeding an arbitrary number, inside a given directory.

(a.o.) [here](http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime) we can read:

> **ctime** is the inode or file change time. The ctime gets updated when the file attributes are changed, like changing the owner, changing the permission or moving the file to an other filesystem but will also be updated when you modify a file.
>   mtime
>
> **mtime** is the file modify time. The mtime gets updated when you modify a file. Whenever you update content of a file or save a file the mtime gets updated.
>
> Most of the times ctime and mtime will be the same, unless only the file attributes are updated. In that case only the ctime gets updated.

#### Having said that

*According to the `ctime`* of a file, the tiny background script below will delete the oldest files if the number of files exceeds a set number. It is yours to decide if that is a usable option in your situation.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os
from operator import itemgetter
import time

dr = sys.argv[1]; n = int(sys.argv[2])

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    # list files; get the number of files
    files = [os.path.join(dr, f) for f in os.listdir(dr)]; nfiles = len(files)
    if nfiles > n:
        # if nfiles exceeds the threshold, get the number of files to delete
        todel = nfiles - n
        # sort the list by creation date, delete the oldest
        del_list = sorted([
            [f, os.path.getctime(f)] for f in files
            ], key=itemgetter(1))[:todel]
        for f in del_list:
            os.remove(f[0])
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `keep_latest.py`
2. Test- run the script from a terminal with the path to your directory and the number of (latest) files to keep as arguments:

   ```
   python3 '/path/to/keep_latest.py' '/path/to/directory' 15
   ```

   to keep the latest 15 files in `'/path/to/directory'`
3. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 '/path/to/keep_latest.py' '/path/to/directory' 15
   ```

#### Other options

The script above is one of the many options. *If* either `mtime` or `ctime` would suffice, another option would be to use [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), and make it do the same as the script above, but *only* if a file is added-, moved- or copied into the directory.

If time accuracy (immediate removal of extra files) is not really important, also a command, run by `cron` would be a good option.

If either the loop of `inotifywait` or the script above would be more efficient would be object of testing and comparing.

Either way, the used resources would be practically none.

Comment: @Arronical Thanks for the edit :) hilareous typos :)

Comment: Easily done, I find I concentrate really hard on the actual code, then make silly errors on the simple part!

Answer (score 0):

bash script

- list files
- if more then limit => start deleting the files until limit reached

```
# create array of files sorted on timestamp (oldest first)
rr=$(find /data/*.tgz -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort)

# if more then 7 tgz files, list the oldest files to array files_to_delete
files_to_delete=$(echo -e "$rr"| awk -v ftd="$(($(echo -e "$rr"| wc -l) - 7))" '{if(ftd<=0) exit; print $NF; if(NR==ftd)exit;}')

# delete the files
echo -e "$file_to_delete" | xargs rm -vf
```